# UITextView editable on iOS5 but not iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a few UITextViews in my App. Since I have started building from XCode 4.5 the UITextView is sort of not editable in iOS6 but built on an iOS5 device they are fully editable.

The code hasnt changed sinced I started using iOS6. The XIB has been around since iOS4

Symptoms are...

iOS6

- Can raise keyboard with tap and delete characters , but cant type anything else
- Cant lower keyboard with keyboard hide key.

iOS5

- Can raise keyboard with tap and edit fully.
- Cant lower keyboard with keyboard hide key.

Im mystified. The `textViewDidBeginEditing:` gets hit so I know its wired up correctly.

Comment: If you can create a simple test project with your delegate methods mostly intact, and make it available on dropbox or equiv.

Comment: Doesnt matter whats in the delegates (for me). I have tried empty stubs and it makes no difference. Also tried instantiating the UITextView from code still cant add text in iOS6

Comment: Like I said, craft a test project and the community (if not me) will find your problem. I spent 8 min at lunch finding a problem someone had been working on for days. Sometimes having different eyes look at it makes a world of difference. Over a million people are using UITextViews in a plethora of apps around the world without issues right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test project approach didnt work as I couldnt reproduce the issue.

In the end the fix was this which wasnt present.

`[window makeKeyAndVisible];`

as in...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

self.viewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController] autorelease];

[window setRootViewController:navigationController];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happened because the `UIAltertView` was called twice.

You might not think you never typed any keys, but the BackSpace key does qualify.

Then I removed the second `UIAlertView` and the `TextField` worked.

I think you need to check the `UIAlertView` code.