# UITextField will not accept input from the keyboard for IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have narrowed this down to only IOS6 devices.

**Original Question:**

I have searched everywhere and tried everything and I simply cannot figure this out!

I have a `UITextField`. When it is selected, the keyboard slides up and the curser begins blinking on the textfield. When I tap the buttons on the keyboard everything behaves normally, the key responds and the curser stops blinking as it should. The only thing is that text is not put into the textfield! It does however accept input from the emoji keyboard. Any help will be very much appreciated!

This is how the `UITextField` is created:

```
UITextField *userInput = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yPos, controlWidth, 26)];
yPos += 32;
[userInput setText:[prompt defaultValue]];
[userInput setPlaceholder:[prompt helpText]];
[userInput setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[userInput setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
[userInput setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]];
[userInput setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[userInput setMinimumFontSize:10];
[userInput setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[userInput setDelegate:self];
[self.scrollView addSubview:userInput];
[self.promptControls addObject:userInput];
[userInput release];
```

This is in a for loop so the number of `UITextField`s depends on how many times the loop is called.

These are the delegate methods I use:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField
{
    self.activeField = aTextField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField
{
    self.activeField = nil;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)aTextField
{
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

`activeField` is a property on the view controller just to determine which field is currently active

I believe that is all the relevant code

Comment: The cursor should not stop blinking. If it did, your program somehow halted (it's probably stuck in an infinite loop if it hasn't crashed outright).

Comment: It does stop blinking just momentarily when you are inputing text, then resumes when you stop

Comment: Try commenting out every line between `initWithFrame:` and `setDelegate`. Does the behavior change? What if you also comment out the delegate line? In any case, none of the code you posted seems to be the culprit. Does this happen both on device and in the simulator?

Comment: Try increasing the width and height of the text field, or decreasing the size of the font.

Comment: The curser does not move. I tried commenting out what you said and the behavior is exactly the same. Apparently this only happens on the iPad, but on iPhone it works

Comment: And it happens both in the iPad simulator and on the device?

Comment: It happens with the ios6 simulator but not the 5.

Comment: Please update the question accordingly; also include info on whether it happens on any actual devices or not (and device/OS version). I'm going to bed now; good luck!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610664/uitextview-editable-on-ios5-but-not-ios6 it might be your problem

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks so much! If you wanted to add that as an answer I would gladly accept it

Comment: A bit weird duping my own answer but it'll make the question clearer. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that you are setting up your window correctly at launch

And that you are calling

`[window setRootViewController:someViewController];`

Which is now an error in iOS6 if you dont and...

`[window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Which isn't an error (to omit) but throws things into wierd land and seems to result in `UITextView` and `UITextField` not working well.

as in...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

self.viewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController] autorelease];

[window setRootViewController:navigationController];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it might be a simple problem of text color. Try to set the text color;

```
[userInput setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that's not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try Commenting `[userInput setDelegate:self];`

Answer (score 0):

This may because the window textfield in not the key window.
Only the key window can accept the user input.
So, try make the [textfield.window makeKeyAndVisible];